# Butterknife + Espresso NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, butterknife

Can Butterknife work with Espresso? I have a test sample, there are 2 activities. In the first activity I print the text, than click the button and send text to another activity. After that I created MainActivityTest and everything worked well. But when I started to use Butterknife I caught the error NoMatchingViewException.

My first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG  = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.first_text)
    EditText mEditText;

    @OnClick(R.id.button_one)
    public void click(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("TEXT",mEditText.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The second activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.second_text)
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("TEXT")!=null) {
            mTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("TEXT"));
        }

    }
}
```

My MainActivityTest:

```
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
            MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void onCreate() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.first_text)).perform(typeText("Test"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button_one)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.second_text)).check(matches(withText("Test")));
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you're missing `ButterKnife.bind(this);`. I don't see it in the code of your activities.

Comment: Butterknife should work absolutely fine with Espresso. It does nothing complicated. It generates a code that got injected into your activity and calls `findViewById` and similar methods.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot  ButterKnife.bind(this). Thank you.